# Cast to ObjectId failed for value error in Mongoose findOne

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I've been struggling with a weird exception and still confused about it after an hour.

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "pedrammarandi@gmail.com"
>   at path "_id" for model "Account"

I'm trying to retrieve an Account via email address. Here is my query

```
export async function getPendingRecipients(user_id, email_address) {
    const account = await Account
        .find({email: email_address})
        .exec();

    return true;
}
```

This is my Schema object

```
const userGmailSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    displayName: String,
    image: Object,
    accessToken: String,
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    refreshToken: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    emails: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Emails'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I guess the problem is you wrote an `id` field.

In MongoDB, the "primary key" is `_id` field, which is an `ObjectId` object (actually it's a 12-byte-value), and in mongoose, `id` is a virtual getter of `_id`, easily said, `id` is an alias of `_id`.

(A little different is that, `_id` returns `ObjectId`, `id` returns `String` version of `_id`.)

By default, mongoose manage `_id` field automatically, so commonly we should not write anything about `id` in schema.

If your `id` is for something like primary key `ID` in SQL DB, just remove it from mongoose schema. If it's means something else in your app, try to add an option:

```
const userGmailSchema = new Schema({
    // your schemas here
}, 
{
    { id: false }  // disable the virtual getter
})
```

or rename it.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is a very important information, without this I was stuck specially because all our ids are custom generated numbers and not object id. So if the id is anything else then ObjectId this property becomes very important to set.